# How to post and get data from SQLite database on objective-c iphone app?

Tags: iphone, sql, sqlite, post, get

I am new for Apple programming or objective-c. I have a task to create an app which can  post and get data from SQLite database which is in remote server. We have the ip address of server and we can access to that database file. Can you give me a little example code that how can i post and get data from SQlite server ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options:

1. You download that sqlite file (if it is not too large), once you have it in disk, you can use sqlite queries to fetch data. Then you do not need to get and post data from sever and your app can act as an offline app once it has data.
2. **Preferred way with respect to your questions**: 
   You will have to create a webservice that will interact with the sqlite file. You will have to install odbc drivers and create oledb connection to your sqlite file in the web service. and then you may do normal get and post as you would for a web service.
3. If you wish to access SQLite file over the network, **then do remeber that sqlite file is a flat file database and only one user can access to it at one point in time**. So a distibuted app trying to access the file may cause issues. Refer [SQlite Network Documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=SqliteNetwork)

Comment: But is there any other database that i can use, that a lot of devices can get data at the same time ? over the network